# how to select 20 rows after specific one

Tags: mysql

well guys i have this table i sorted by date and all the id are mixed now
and i selected 20 first rows then want  to get another 20 rows after the last one
to make is more clear : ('SELECT * FROM switch ORDER BY from_date ASC')

```
id  what    employee    from_date
55  1   11223   2012-01-26
69  3   30182   2012-01-12
67  3   12312   2031-01-12
68  3   12312   2031-01-12
65  3   12312   2031-01-12
6   3   12312   2031-01-12
64  3   12312   2031-01-12
63  3   12312   2031-01-12
**62    3   12312   2012-01-31**
60  3   30182   2012-01-18
61  3   30182   2012-01-18
59  3   30182   2012-01-18
57  3   30182   2012-01-18
58  3   30182   2012-01-18
```

now i want to get 20 rows from this table after id=62
the output should give me:

```
60  3   30182   2012-01-18
61  3   30182   2012-01-18
59  3   30182   2012-01-18
57  3   30182   2012-01-18
58  3   30182   2012-01-18
```

Comment: right sir, and thanks for fixing the viewing issue for me

Comment: ANY ONE ??? I REALLY NEED IT. it should be something like: SELECT * FROM switch WHERE ROWNUM() > (SELECT id FROM users WHERE id= $id as ROWNUM) ORDER BY from_date ASC

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately I didn't get by what column you're ordering, however this will work for all.

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY column_name ASC LIMIT 20, 20
```

This will return 20 rows after 20th row.
In your case query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM switch ORDER BY from_date ASC LIMIT 20, 20
```

Comment: Actually he did: `SELECT * FROM switch ORDER BY from_date ASC`

Comment: @zerkms its looks like that author edited his post, so I'll update my answer

Comment: im assigning it to my update function which will update data from a big database, (this databse is dynamic and change contanly), so the function grabs each time 20 results ordered by date, display them and keep the last id in var. now i want to grab each time 20 more rows starting from the id stored in var (because counting 20 each time might ending up giving me results already given because the db has changed)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain a little more. What exactly are you trying to get from the table? If your ordering by date I assume you are trying to grab data based on the date. But you are stating you wish to grab it by the id? This might be what you are looking for...

```
select top 20 * from [table] where [condition]
union all
select top 20 * from [table] where [condition]
```

-try, try, try, got it!

Comment: im assigning it to my update function which will update data from a big database, (this databse is dynamic and change contanly), so the function grabs each time 20 results ordered by date, display them and keep the last id in var. now i want to grab each time 20 more rows starting from the id stored in var (because counting 20 each time might ending up giving me results already given because the db has changed)

Comment: Thank you I believe I understand a little more now. So each time this function runs you want it to display 20 results ordered by date and then the next 20? I'll post a little code on this. Sorry another thought are you able to create #temp tables or will it take to long because of the number of rows?

Comment: well.... each query will pop around 3000 results so i want it to use the minimum resources as possible